# AC-DC Schematic - Is this a Death Capacitor

Tags: power-supply, power, mains, safety, ac-dc

Is this a death cap? I think it's not a death cap because it doesn't connect to the DC ground, but I'm not 100% sure.

[image]
Image Source: Hi-Link HLK-20M24 Datasheet - https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/30/HLK-20M12.pdf

This is one example of a death capacitor.

[image]
Image Source: https://robrobinette.com/Death_Cap_and_Ground_Switch.htm

Comment: Define "Death Capacitor".

Comment: If it's suitably rated for that connection, X2 for instance, it's fine. Define 'death cap'.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_phalloides Is the only death cap I’m familiar with.

Comment: Touch the wires whilst powered and death might be an outcome. The internal Ycapacitor is more likely to zap you.

Comment: @Kartman "zap" is probably the wrong expression.  Those kind of capacitors are sort of creating a tingling when brushing an affected surface lightly.  Once contact intensifies, the tingling goes away.  The effect will be definitely more conspicuous with 230V installations than with 120V.  It was the reason I only used grounded power supplies with my T61 Thinkpad laptop: its frontal Firewire port otherwise became a frequent distraction because it was in the line of touch for the left hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the cap is between mains live and neutral, it is not between mains and other parts.

As the datasheet you linked says, it is fr filtering and to pass EMC certifications, and it needs to be a certain safety class capacitor rated for safe connection to mains.

Now, what you may call the "death cap" would be an EMI filter cap between mains input and low voltage output to prevent high frequency common mode apppearing on output. That may still be internal to the module so it can't be removed, but if it is there, it would be a modern safety rated capacitor with correct safety class which is designed to fail open instead of failing short and presenting mains directly on output.

Comment: Thanks Justme, that helps.